# Copy the list using List Template in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sub-site, list-template, copy

I need to copy a list to a sub-site on Sharepoint Online. Both use modern experience.

I tried the "save as a template" method, but the templates which are in the main site only work for the main site itself.
I can see the templates as apps (intuitive isn't it?) that I can add to the main site, BUT they don't show up in the sub-site. And there's no template gallery at all for it.

I also tried to create a new list "based on an existing list", but that invariably fails (with no error codes, just "sorry, something went wrong. Try again later").

I tried to re-upload the saved templates (.stp files) into the sub-site by using the upload->template feature in the document library. But that seemingly does nothing.

(RANT: I think this is appalling, and it sure is frustrating to be searching around for 2 days in order to achieve something as simple as copying a DB.)

any suggestions? 
TA

Comment: switch the subsite to Sharepoint Classic experience, then check if the list template shows up.

Comment: that did not work

Comment: Late to the party. If you created an STP on an English site, you can only import on an English site. Manually change the language in STP with: https://nikcharlebois.com/changing-sharepoint-list-template-language/

Answer (score 0):

We can try any one of the below approaches

**Approach 1:**

1. Export list item into excel from the main site
2. Go to Site content where you want create the list
3. Add and App using Import Spreadsheet (Select the exported excel here)

**Note :** It is not support attachments,timestamps, created, modified.

**Approach 2:**

1. Connect the main(source) site using sharegate tool
2. Connect the destination site using sharegate tool
3. Use Copy content/ Copy structure method to migrate your content

**Note:** Sharegate supports the attachments,timestamps, created, modified.

Comment: so the only working solution to a problem so simple is a third party SW? thanks but no thanks. I'd rather rebuild the tables and use powershell to migrate the data

Answer (score 0):

The Web Designer Galleries feature is only available in root site collections instead of the subsites. So you will not see the template gallery under subsite.

You can download the list template to the local and then upload the list template to the List templates list in destination root site collection. Then the list template will be an app in the destination root site collection and its subsites. Then you will be able to add an app for the list template in the subsites.

I am able to copy the list based on your description in the Modern site.

Refer to the below link for more reference:

[How to use List Template, created in one subsite, at another subsite](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-use-list-template-created-in-one-subsite-at/8a4a911e-9ae6-42c5-90fb-0e6d3286018a)

[Manage list templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393)

Answer (score 0):

By default, sub site shall inherit the list template gallery from parent site. I test in my end and the list template show up in sub site apps. Have a check on the site feature `Team Collaboration lists`. Make sure you have enable it, and the user account try to create list have at least read permission in List Template gallery.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Team Collaboration Lists is already enabled. How do I change the List Template Gallery permissions? Anyway I also tried to add the custom "app" using the admin account, which is also the owner of the gallery, but the "apps" wouldn't show up

Comment: could it be that the apps aren't visibile because the subsite is in english while the site collection is in italian? (btw I have no idea why, but if I create a new subsite using the italian template, it will always turn out to be using the english template)

Comment: @Valentino It seems be better to open a service request about this strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the approach below

Approach 1. You could add the list inside your subsite and generate a site template base on that subsite.

Note:

- You need to have all the list items inside the list so you
  could have the items carried over on site creation
- on saving your subsite as template you need to check the 'Include Site
  Contents' option.
- By default, option to save site as template is turned off for Sharepoint Online, follow steps on how to enable it: [here](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/missing-save-site-as-template-option-in-sharepoint-online-office-365-and-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Approach 2: You can have a script inside your subsite that will copy the list inside your subsite. You can have it run on page load (just make sure you check if the list is already created so it won't create more instances).

Note: In sharepoint online, you will need to learn spfx for webpart or extension customization. OR you can use the Modern Script Editor so you could embed a script in classic sharepoint way, just build and upload the package in app catalog.[Modern Script Editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)

Best of luck.

Comment: I don't understand what you're going on about. The original list is located in the site collection. The sub-site is empty. I need the list to be moved to the sub-site. Cheers.